# Calculating the maximum free store memory consumed by a process

Tags: linux, unix, memory-management

I would like to compare the maximum amount of heap a set of processes dynamically allocate. Is there any system command in Linux or any application that automatically does that? Something like a monitoring tool that runs a process and watches for how much memory is consumed by the process.

Unfortunately, the `size(1)` command only reflects on the *text* and *data* memory sections of the process and process accounting reports on the average memory used by the process.

Comment: Um, you mean other than `top`?

Comment: How do I know the maximum memory usage by a process using top? Keep watching at the memory usage values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pmap is not bad, but it only gives you a snapshot, not the maximum.

You might want to take a look at [getrusage()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage).  On new-ish kernels (2.6.32; not sure the exact cut-off), the ru_*rss fields are actually populated.  (On older kernels, they always get set to zero...)

Also try "cat /proc/<pid>/status" and look at VmPeak (which shows the peak virtual memory usage) and VmHWM (which shows the peak resident set size).  Those are both "high water marks", as in they go up during a process's lifetime but never down.  If you can grab a snapshot of them at process termination, you can gather the data yourself.

I once wrote a .so to do just that; it worked by patching exit() (and you invoked it using LD_PRELOAD).  But it was for work and I do not have a copy :-(.

Answer (score 3):

Try with a memory profiler like [valgrind massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html).